# MFC (C++): Why control on top does not receive event?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

At design stage,

- A (List Box) is drawn before B (List Ctrl)
- A is invisible initially
- A covers part of B

During runtime, a button toggles the visibility of A, and when A is visible places it on top of B (using SetWindowPos(...)).

When A is shown, it does not receive events in the overlapping area (e.g., when I click "item 4" and "item 5" in the figure below). Why and how to fix it?

[image]

The sample code can be accessed here https://138.197.210.223/test/test.zip.

Comment: What are A and B? Do you get the 'event' message when there is no overlap?

Comment: I guess you are talking about a dialog resource. You Experiment with the tab order (it's the order the controls appear in the script - and no, you can't specify the drawing order), and the clip-siblings property (style). And of course control A must be able to receive mouse input. You can also try to set the Z-order programmatically.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou, You are right, A has tab order behind B. Another point: initially A's visible is false. Does it affect? Anyway, I see A covers B, but when I click the overlapping area, A has no response. If I remove B, A has response.

Comment: Try putting control A before B in the tab order. If B hides A in this setting, set the clip siblings style for B. This should work. But I don't know if such a UI design (ie A being before B in the tab order) would be acceptable (although I can't imagine a design where two overlapping controls would be both accepting user input). Alternatively you can try removing the Notify style from B (again, if this would be acceptable).

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou, I edit the question, please take a look, thank you. I also try your suggestion of "WS_CLIPSIBLINGS" in rc file, which does not work.

Comment: @lakeweb, re-edited, please take a look. Thank you.

Comment: So, what notification do you want to receive from A? Click, selection changed or something else? Which event exactly?

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou, selection change when clicking "item 4" or "item 5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did check the code, and found that the problem was caused by the `::SetWindowPos()` command in `OnBnClickedCheck1()`. You call it to solve a drawing problem, but you do so by changing the Z-Order, and this causes the B control to capture the input instead. So it must be removed, and the code in `OnBnClickedCheck1()` can be changed as shown below (I have simplified the syntax, and used MFC, rather than WinAPI commands):

```
void CTestDlgActXDlg::OnBnClickedCheck1()
{
        m_list_A.ShowWindow(m_list_A.IsWindowVisible() ? SW_HIDE : SW_SHOW);
}
```

The drawing problem can be solved by setting the `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` style in the resource script, as suggested in the comments:

```
.
.
LISTBOX         IDC_LIST_A,114,36,48,42,LBS_SORT | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | NOT WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
CONTROL         "",IDC_LIST_B,"SysListView32",LVS_ALIGNLEFT | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,108,60,60,54
.
.
```

This way it works for me, the A control takes precedence over B, and sends `LBN_SELCHANGE` notifications, for any of its items clicked.

And something strange I have noticed, the `DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST_B, m_list_B);` command in testdlg.cpp is run twice. Delete the 2nd call.

Weird UI design btw.