# How to add a Checkbox in a CView that is visible over a control

Tags: button, mfc

I want to add Checkboxes in a `CView` derived class, but it is constantly hidden below a chart control.
I am struggling to set the correct parameters. And I am now not sure, if this is possible.
What I have tried:

- Set the TopMostStyle
- Set the parent to the chartCtrl, works, but then the Button messages does not route to the `CView`

  ```
  void CMyView::OnInitialUpdate()
  {
     :
     m_wndCurveCtrl.Create(rcTemp, this, 123, WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE /*| WS_CLIPSIBLINGS*/);

     myButton.Create(_T("MyChxBox), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_AUTOCHECKBOX, CRect(100, 5, 200, 25), this, ID_BTN1);
     myButton.SetWindowPos(&CWnd::wndTopMost, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_DRAWFRAME);    // topMOst over a ChartCtrl   (not working)       
  }
  ```

---

Update add sample control to show the effect:
`Invalidate()` Brings the checkboxes behind the chart control. It does not respect the `WS_STYLE`!?
Added a workaround "Fake Invalidate" with `MoveWindow()` too.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyChartControl, CWnd)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CMyCurveControl::Create(const RECT& rect, CWnd* pParentWnd, UINT nID, DWORD dwStyle /*= WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE*/)
{
    ASSERT(pParentWnd->GetSafeHwnd());
    if (!CWnd::Create(NULL, L"MyChartCtrl", dwStyle, rect, pParentWnd, nID))
        return FALSE;
}

void CMyCurveControl::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here
    // Do not call CWnd::OnPaint() for painting messages
    CRect rc;
    GetClientRect(rc);

    rc.DeflateRect(10, 10);
    dc.FillSolidRect(rc, RGB(230, 230, 0));     // Draw A Yellow Rect
}

void CMyCurveControl::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    Invalidate();       // This is the devil !  other HWND_TOP Checkboxes goes now behind this control

    // Fake Invalidate() that works here
/*  CRect rc;
    GetWindowRect(rc);
    ScreenToClient(rc);
    MoveWindow(rc);
*/
    CWnd::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful, if you would expose more code, e.g. about the chart control. If you draw it yourself, you might want to do it in `OnEraseBkgnd()` / `WM_ERASEBKGND`. This way, all other controls are being drawn on top of the chart graphics.

Comment: Done. `OnEraseBkgnd()` has here the same effect as in`OnPaint`.

Answer (score 1):

Is the "chart" control (what is it exactly?) a child of the CView window as well? Then try setting the `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` style for the chart control but NOT for the check-box. If the style does not appear in the Properties Editor you can add it in the resource script, using Visual Studio's Text Editor (will ask you to Close the resource editor first, answer OK). Or you can set it by calling `CWnd::ModifyStyle()` or the Win32 `GetWindowLong()`/`SetWindowLong()` functions. Do not call `SetWindowPos()`.

Comment: No success with `WS_CLIBSIBLING`. :( It is my own CWnd derived chart control, where I paint the curves in `OnPaint` I set the style direct with `m_pTempCtrl->Create(rcTemp, this, ID_TEMP_CONTROL, WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS);`

Comment: @TomTom, it definitely works with [controls of a dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60085583/mfc-c-why-control-on-top-does-not-receive-event/60103793#60103793), maybe there are some additional properties that need to be set. Also try creating the two windows in the opposite order. You may also copy your project and start removing stuff until you get a MRE - a lot could be removed, like the document class could be emptied and the chart control could just draw a hard-coded circle, instead of real "curves" (from the input data).

Comment: I found now what happens. It works all as expect until I call `Invalidate()` for the chart control.  Then it does not respect `WS_STYLE`. The checkboxes goes invisible, hidden by the control.   
I have now a workaround for this issue:  If I replace `m_wndCurveCtrl.Invalidate()` with `m_wndCurveCtrl.MoveWindow()`. then this brings the checkboxes back again.  I do not unterstand this magic!?