# How draw a CButton over a OCX control in MFC Dialog Box

Tags: mfc

I have a Dialog based MFC Application. In this Dialog Box I have to put :

1. A third-party OCX control
2. Several MFC `CButton` buttons.

The pre-said OCX must cover full Dialog Size (this is a mandatory request) ; in fact in `OnSize(..)` function , I have to "move" the OCX window until dialog are is covered. This unfortunately causes the buttons to be fully covered by OCX so that they are invisible.

Is there a way to fix this? Do I have to create custom buttons derived from `CButton` with special characteristics? If so, how?

I tried a MFC with OCX and few buttons but buttons are invisible.

Comment: The easiest solution certainly is to have your dialog set aside part of its client area to display its custom controls (such as a button). Displaying a control on top of another control generally requires support from this other control. If your OCX/ActiveX control isn't prepared to host custom controls, there's little hope to implement this in a reliable fashion.

Comment: One stab in the dark - what if you change the tab order? Doesn't that affect the order of rendering? But still sounds like an odd thing to do. To resize a control to overlay other controls.

Comment: You can try for to set the parent for the buttons to the OCX-control, but with his drawbacks. I have a similar problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75606313/how-to-add-a-checkbox-in-a-cview-that-is-visible-over-a-control/75622164?noredirect=1#comment133428571_75622164)